# Can't login gmail in the background Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, gmail

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
user_agent = 'My user agent'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, version_main=109)
driver.get('https://gmail.com')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="identifierId"]').send_keys(gmail)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('other.png')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('onasini.png')
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys(gmail_password)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button').click()
```

I tried everything but nothing worked, I needed to log in to Gmail using the `"headless"` argument
or in the background and it was showing this error `"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id= "password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"}"`. I worked with `undetected_chromedriver`

Comment: edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding, using `sendkeys()` and `click()` is not working on Goolge. because they detect bots by that. so another way is use `pyautogui`.

It does work, but while script is running, you cannot use user mouse or keyboard. because pyautogui are using. and also cannot use `headless` option

```
import pyautogui
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

user_id = "YOUR ID"
user_pw = "YOUR PASSWORD"

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)

driver.get(url='https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ko&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F'
        '%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&ec=GAZAmgQ&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')

time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.write(user_id)
pyautogui.press('tab', presses=3)
pyautogui.press('enter')

time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.write(user_pw)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

this is work on

```
python==3.9
selenium==4.1.5
undetected-chromedriver==3.4.6
PyAutoGUI==0.9.53
```